# IdentityServer4 login loops back to login page again after successful sign-on

Tags: authentication, identityserver4

I use IdentityServer4 in my mvc app accessing web API. It's been working perfectly without any issues while we are using HTTPS. But recently, we need to set up an internal testing environment using HTTP, instaed of HTTPS. All we did was changing the configurations of all the urls from HTTPS to HTTPS but after that, the login page loops back to the same login page again after a successful user login. This only happens when the login succeeded. If I type in wrong credentials, for instance, the correct message will disply.

What's possibly going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use HTTPS when working with IdentityServer and OpenID Connect and this is due to the **SameSite** attribute that will otherwise block the cookies in the browser. There is no real workaround for this.

you can create locally trusted certificates using tools like MKCERT https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Thanks Tore. That was my guess and sorry to hear the confirmation. HTTPS has been working for us with a self-signed certificate, until recently, when all our servers were upgraded to 2019. Thanks again.